# ¿Por qué no sale reportviewer cuando estoy enviando parametros correctamente?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, reportviewer, dataset

Buenas tengo éste código que lo que hace es mandar a llamar un tableadapter, mandar su parametro para llenar el datatable en el dataset, cuando envio los parametros todo carga bien pero cuando empieza a cargar el reportviewer sale éste mensaje.
(En el reporte tengo un tablix que se llena con los campos de "CamposConsolidado" y su origen de datos es el dataset.)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está el codigo que utilizo para enviar el parametro al TableAdapter.

Muchas gracias.

```
            switch (ventana)
            {               
                case "Facturar Consolidados":
                this.dt_cls_generacion_consolidadoTableAdapter.Fill(this.wmpDataSet.dt_cls_generacion_consolidado, parametro);
                //se agregan datos a los parametros estaticos del reporte
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"RPTS\RPTSConsolidados.rdlc");
                RP.Add(new ReportParameter("FechaGenero", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMMM/yyyy").ToUpper()));
                RP.Add(new ReportParameter("FechaGenero2", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(RP);
                break;
            default:
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Ya he solucionado el problema.
Gracias.

Comment: ahora si ya tienes la solución considera añadirlo como respuesta siguiendo [answer]